# Promise.then bind issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have been facing an issue in binding a value to next Promise. Look at the following code, it will explain the situation better.

```
'use strict';

function FindEvent(eventId) {
    console.log('Event:', eventId);
    return Promise.resolve({title: 'MyEvent'});
}

function FindUser(userId) {
    console.log('User:', userId);
    return Promise.resolve({username: 'MyUser'});
}

function MyServiceProblem(payload) {
    payload.userId = 'blah';
    return FindEvent(payload.eventId)
        .then((event) => {
            payload.userId = 'test';
            // setting a breakpoint here shows
            // that the value to payload.userId has been
            // assigned, i.e. 'test'

            return Promise.resolve(payload);
        })
        .then(FindUser.bind(this, payload.userId));
        // But new value doesn't reaches inside FindUser
}

MyServiceProblem({ // userId is 'blah', why not 'test'
    eventId: '456'
});

function MyServiceWorks(payload) {
    payload.userId = 'blah';
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        payload.userId = 'test';

        return resolve(payload);
    })
        .then(FindUser.bind(this, payload.userId));
        // From here, the 'test' value reaches FindUser
}

MyServiceWorks({ // userId is 'test'
    eventId: '456'
});
```

The question is, why the value it binds is different for both cases. Both are exactly the same, except this one is first resolving the part of promise and then assigning a value to `payload.userId`.

Comment: In MyServiceWorks you are returning promise, but in findUser you are returning Promise.resolve

Comment: So what it has to do with binding a value in the next promises?

Comment: I think you might want to try  `return new Promise.resolve(payload);` in `MyServiceProblem`. The `new` is important.

Comment: @Ali, it throws an error.
`TypeError: function resolve() { [native code] } is not a constructor`

Comment: It looks like 'bind' happens before function inside .then, when payload didn't have any property called userId

Comment: if `bind` happens before function inside `.then()`, then why it didn't happen in `MyServiceWorks` function?

Comment: @Avinash, I have updated the question, have a look again. Now `payload.userId` has initial value `blah` in both cases. It updates it to `test` in `Works` case, but it doesn't update it in the `Problem` case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down your code a little bit. You have

```
function MyServiceProblem(payload) {
    payload.userId = 'blah';
    return FindEvent(payload.eventId)
        .then((event) => {
            payload.userId = 'test';

            return Promise.resolve(payload);
        })
        .then(FindUser.bind(this, payload.userId));
}
```

the issue is that your `.bind` will run before your callback. This code could also be written as

```
function MyServiceProblem(payload) {
    payload.userId = 'blah';

    var firstThenCallback = (event) => {
        payload.userId = 'test';
        return Promise.resolve(payload);
    };
    var secondThenCallback = FindUser.bind(this, payload.userId);

    return FindEvent(payload.eventId)
        .then(firstThenCallback)
        .then(secondThenCallback);
}
```

The `payload` object is shared across everything, but the `payload.userId` is passed into `.bind` before `firstThenCallback` has had a chance to execute.

Rather that using `.bind` and passing the value immediately, it seems like your simplest solution would be to use an anonymous function so the `userId` value is only read later.

```
function MyServiceProblem(payload) {
    payload.userId = 'blah';
    return FindEvent(payload.eventId)
        .then((event) => {
            payload.userId = 'test';

            return Promise.resolve(payload);
        })
        .then(() => FindUser(payload.userId));
}
```

It's not at all clear why you've written such round-about promise code either, but I assume this is a trimmed-down example? Why are you resolving with `payload` instead of just calling `FindUser` in that function, e.g.

```
function MyServiceProblem(payload) {
    payload.userId = 'blah';
    return FindEvent(payload.eventId)
        .then((event) => {
            payload.userId = 'test';

            return FindUser(payload.userId);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
I wrote the code that way because it becomes more readable when I collapse all the `then()`s.. It reads like this: `FindEvent().then(FindUser()).then(doOtherThing())`. I'm obviously not getting only the `userId` from `findEvent()`.